# Capture string between specific characters

Tags: ruby, regex

Can someone help me extract the string:

```
Advice about something
```

from below:

```
&lt;TITLE&gt;Advice about something&lt;/TITLE&gt;
```

The expression should be able to capture the string between `&lt;TITLE&gt;` and `&lt;/TITLE&gt;`. I tried expressions such as `[^TITLE&lt;g\/]`, but couldn't get the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the left part `&lt;TITLE&gt;` and the right part `&lt;/TITLE&gt;` and put `(.*?)` in between:
`&lt;TITLE&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/TITLE&gt;`

[**Online demo**](http://rubular.com/r/xMxc2fjJcG)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a robust solution rather than a temporal hack, then use specific parsers.

```
require "cgi"
require "nokogiri"
Nokogiri.parse(CGI.unescapeHTML(
  "&lt;TITLE&gt;Advice about something&lt;/TITLE&gt;"
))
.xpath("TITLE").text
# => "Advice about something"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Is the string always delimited by semi-columns?

```
tmp = "&lt;TITLE&gt;Advice about something&lt;/TITLE&gt;"
=> "&lt;TITLE&gt;Advice about something&lt;/TITLE&gt;" 

tmp.split(';')[2].gsub(/\&lt/, "")
=> "Advice about something"
```

Comment: The answer should contain a regex based solution. Array#split is naive and not a general solution.

Comment: You could use something like this    string= "&lt;TITLE&gt;Advice about something&lt;/TITLE&gt;"     (CGI::unescapeHTML string).gsub(/\<\/*\w*\>/,'')